# Is it possible to set up relations in DB automatically?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have MS SQL Server database and it doesn't have any relations between tables. How can I set up them automatically? Can you suggest any tools for that task?

Comment: How should a tool know how to set it?

Comment: @juergend maybe by names of rows in the tables